# Using functions in PHP Method

Tags: php

I have a db class that I've been using for years. I noticed something interesting today.

```
function example_function($key)
{
    global $db; // db variable - class
    $a_id = 1; // example
    $admins = $db->table('admins')->where('id','=',$a_id)->order('id','desc')->limit(1)->get();
    $admin_data = $admins['data'][0];
    $return = $admin_data[$key];
    return $return;
}

$id = example_function('id');
$new = $db->table('rooms')->where('id','=',$id)->order('id','desc')->limit(2)->get();
print_r($new);
//WORKS


$new = $db->table('rooms')->where('id','=',2)->order('id','desc')->limit(2)->get();
print_r($new);
//WORKS

$new = $db->table('rooms')->where('id','=',example_function('id'))->order('id','desc')->limit(2)->get();
print_r($new);
//NOT WORKING ?
```

`->where('id','=',example_function('id'))->`

When I use an external function in this part, things get messy.

But the following also works. When doing another operation with the db in the relevant function, things get messy.

```
function example_function($key)
{
    return '1';
}


$new = $db->table('rooms')->where('id','=',example_function('id'))->order('id','desc')->limit(2)->get();
```

Is the problem in global usage? Or is the database class wrong?

DB CLASS

````
class DB
{
    protected $connect;
    protected $db_database = DB_DATABASE;
    protected $db_host = DB_HOST;
    protected $db_username = DB_USERNAME;
    protected $db_password = DB_PASSWORD;
    protected $db_name = DB_NAME;
    protected $db_prefix = DB_PREFIX;
    
    
    //parameters
    
    protected $error = null;
    protected $last_id = null;
    protected $query = null;
    protected $from = null;
    protected $select = '*';
    protected $where = null;
    protected $group = null;
    protected $order = null;
    protected $limit = null;
    protected $pagination_type = false;
    protected $per_page = 0;
    protected $get_arr = null;
    function __construct() 
    {      
        try {
             $this->connect = new PDO("{$this->db_database}:host={$this->db_host};dbname={$this->db_name};charset=utf8mb4", "{$this->db_username}", "{$this->db_password}");
             $this->connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
             $this->connect->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES utf8mb4");
        } catch ( PDOException $e ){
             echo  "<b>Veritabanı bağlantısı sağlanamadı! - Hata Kodu: </b>".$e->getMessage();
             exit;
        }
    }
    public function now($type="datetime")
    {
        switch($type)
        {
            case 'timestamp';
            return time();
            case 'date';
            return date('-m-d');
            case 'datetime';
            return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            default:
            return date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            
        }
        
    }
    public function m_empty($data)
    {
        if($data=='' and $data!='0')
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    public function query($query,$arr=false)
    {
        $this->reset();
        if($query!="")
        {
            
            try 
            {
                
                $run =  $this->connect->prepare($query);
                if($arr)
                {
                    if(is_array($arr))
                    {
                        $run->execute($arr);
                        return $run;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $run->execute(array($arr));
                        return $run;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $run->execute();
                    return $run;
                }
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                $this->error = $e->getMessage();
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    public function table($table)
    {
         $this->from = $this->db_prefix . $table;
        return $this;
    }
    public function select($fields)
    {
        $this->select = $fields;
        return $this;
    }
    public function where($field,$op='=',$values,$and="AND")
    {
        if(!$this->m_empty($field))
        {
            if(is_null($this->where))
            {
                $this->where="{$field} {$op} ?";
                $this->get_arr[] = $values;
            }
            else
            {
                
                $this->where.=" {$and} {$field} {$op} ?";
                $this->get_arr[] = $values;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function where_set($field,$op='=',$values,$and="AND")
    {
        if(!$this->m_empty($field) and !$this->m_empty($values))
        {
            if(is_null($this->where))
            {
                $this->where="{$field} {$op} {$values}";
            }
            else
            {
                
                $this->where.=" {$and} {$field} {$op} {$values}";
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function group($fields)
    {
        if(is_null($this->group))
        {
            $this->group = $fields;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->group .=",{$fields}";
        
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function order($field,$type="desc")
    {
        if(!is_null($field))
        {
            if(is_null($this->order))
            {
                if(strtolower($field)=="rand()")
                {
                    $this->order = $field;
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->order = $field.' '.strtoupper($type);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(strtolower($field)=="rand()")
                {
                    $this->order .=",{$fields}";
                }
                else
                {
                    $this->order .= ','.$field.' '.strtoupper($type);
                }
            }
        
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function limit($start,$end=null)
    {
        if(is_null($end))
        {
            if(is_numeric($start))
            {
                $this->limit = $start;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(is_numeric($start) and is_numeric($end))
            {
                $this->limit = "{$start},{$end}";
            }
        
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function pagination($per_page)
    {
        if(is_numeric($per_page))
        {
            $this->per_page = $per_page;
            $this->pagination_type = true;
        }
        return $this;
    }
    public function get()
    {
        $query = "SELECT {$this->select} FROM {$this->from}";
        if(!is_null($this->where))
        {
            $query.=" where {$this->where}";
        }
        if(!is_null($this->group))
        {
            $query.=" group by {$this->group}";
        }
        if(!is_null($this->order))
        {
            $query.=" order by {$this->order}";
        }
        if($this->pagination_type)
        {
            $c_per_page = $this->per_page;
            $c_arr = $this->get_arr;
            $extra_query = preg_replace("#SELECT (.*?) FROM#","SELECT COUNT(*) as total_count FROM",$query);
            $all = $this->query($extra_query,$this->get_arr);
            if($all)
            {
                    $total_count = $all->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)[0]['total_count'];
                    $page_count = ceil($total_count/$c_per_page);
                    $current_page = (integer)m_u_g(DB_PAGINATION_GET) ? (integer)m_u_g(DB_PAGINATION_GET) : 1;
                    $current_limit=($current_page - 1) * $c_per_page;
                    $query = $query." limit {$current_limit},{$c_per_page}";
                    $current_rows = $this->query($query,$c_arr);
                    $data = $current_rows->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $return = array();
                    $return['total_count'] = $total_count;
                    $return['current_count'] = count($data);
                    $return['total_page'] = $page_count;
                    $return['current_page'] = $current_page;
                    $return['data'] = $data;
                    return $return;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(!is_null($this->limit))
            {
                $query.=" limit {$this->limit}";
            }
            
            $gets = $this->query($query,$this->get_arr);
            if($gets)
            {
                    $data = $gets->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    $return = array();
                    $return["total_count"] = count($data);
                    $return["data"] = $data;
                    return $return;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    public function get_var($field)
    {
        if($this->m_empty($field))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            $query = "SELECT {$field} FROM {$this->from}";
            if(!is_null($this->where))
            {
                $query.=" where {$this->where}";
            }
            if(!is_null($this->order))
            {
                $query.=" order by id desc limit 1";
            }
            $gets = $this->query($query,$this->get_arr);
            if($gets)
            {
                    return  $gets->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)[0][$field];
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
    }
    public function get_vars($table,$where,$var,$type=true)
    {
        if($type)
        {
                $data = $this->connect->query("select $var from $table where $where order by id desc limit 1")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        else
        {
               $data = $this->connect->query("select $var from $table where $where")->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
    
        return $data["$var"];
        
    }
    public function count()
    {
        $grouped = false;
        $query = "SELECT count(*) as total_count FROM {$this->from}";
        if(!is_null($this->where))
        {
            $query.=" where {$this->where}";
        }
        if(!is_null($this->group))
        {
            $grouped = true;
            $query.=" group by {$this->group}";
        }
        if(!is_null($this->order))
        {
            $query.=" order by {$this->order}";
        }
        $gets = $this->query($query,$this->get_arr);
        if($gets)
        {
                if($grouped)
                {
                    $count = 0;
                    foreach($gets->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $counts)
                    {
                        $count = $count+$counts["total_count"];
                    }
                    return $count;
                }
                else
                {
                    return $gets->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)["total_count"];
                }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public function insert(array $data)
    {
        if(is_array($data))
        {
            $query = 'INSERT INTO '.$this->from;
            $keys = array_keys($data);
            $query.=' ('.implode(',',$keys).') values (';
            $query_add='';
            $values = array_values($data);
            foreach($values as $val)
            {
                $query_add.='?,';
            }
            $query_add = trim($query_add,',');
            $query.=$query_add.')';
            if($this->query($query,$values))
            {
                
                $this->last_id = $this->connect->lastInsertId();
                return $this->last_id;
            }
            else
            {
                
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
    public function update(array $data)
    {
        if(is_array($data))
        {
            $query = "UPDATE {$this->from} set";
            $keys = array_keys($data);
            $values = array_values($data);
            $query_add = '';
            foreach($keys as $key)
            {
                $query_add.=" {$key} = ?,";
            }
            $query_add = trim($query_add,',');
            $query.=$query_add;
            
            if(!is_null($this->where))
            {
                $query.=" where {$this->where}";
            }
            $new = array_merge($values,$this->get_arr);
            if($this->query($query,$new))
            {
                
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }
    public function delete()
    {
        $query = "DELETE FROM {$this->from}";
        if(!is_null($this->where))
        {
            $query.=" where {$this->where}";
        }
        if($this->query($query,$this->get_arr))
        {
            
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            
            return false;
        }

    }
    public function error()
    {
        return $this->error;
        
    }
    public function last_id()
    {
        return $this->last_id;
    }
    protected function reset()
    {
        $this->error = null;
        $this->last_id = null;
        $this->query = null;
        $this->from = null;
        $this->select = '*';
        $this->where = null;
        $this->group = null;
        $this->order = null;
        $this->limit = null;
        $this->pagination_type = false;
        $this->per_page = 0;
        $this->get_arr = null;
    }
}
$db = new DB();
?>```
````

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: I suspect your DB class can't deal with the fact that the function being called performs another database query in the middle of constructing your query.

Comment: What are you considering messy and/or the problem?

Comment: @Barmar No I am getting an error. But when I try the example that doesn't work. Database class is not assigned to the "rooms" table.

Comment: It's not about function calls in general, it's because `example_function()` contains another query.

Comment: Does it work if you do `$variable = example_function('id')` and then use `->where('id', '=', $variable)`?

Comment: Does your database class support joins? That seems to be what you're trying to do with this nested query.

Comment: @Barman Yes it works when I use it like that. But this slows me down.

Comment: If it works that way, this failure is a design problem in your database class.

Comment: @Barman Can you help if I share the DB class?

Comment: Why are you asking Barman instead of Barmar? Hint: When you're typing a username, use TAB for completion and it will never misspell.

Comment: You can add the class to the question if it's not too big. But maybe you should use an existing ORM (e.g. Laravel) instead of trying to design your own.

Comment: @Barmar I am so sorry. Yes, I spelled it wrong. I noticed your name sensitivity when I looked at your profile.

I suspect there is an error in the reset process. I add the class to the question. Could you help me I would be grateful.

Comment: This appears to be caused by the utilization of `global $db` and the default PHP mutability of objects, instead of `$db = new ...`. Assuming the DB class methods are not immutable, this causes `WHERE id = ` to not be completed before being overwritten by `example_function()` uses the same object instance to begin another query `$db->table('admins')...`. You would need to call `example_function()` outside of the same `$db` instance to ensure both queries are completed. Sadly almost all DBALs suffer from the same issue. Best bet would be to use `clone` to separate the instances.

Comment: That's probably right. `example_function` should create its own DB instance instead of using `global $db;`

Comment: @Barmar You're right, a new instance can be created. But that means one more new database base connection. Performance concerns... Did you see my class?

Comment: Make the connection a `static` property and it can be reused without duplication and then you have a separate DBAL for creating query strings.

Comment: @WillB. I want to do this job without creating a new instance. But I don't know if it makes sense.

I wonder if I make the connection static and use DB::table.... in all transactions?

Comment: With the current usage of `global` and calling methods on a single instance of a mutable object that is changing the value of a single property when the intent is to have two separate values (separate instances) at the same time. if you do not want to create a separate DB instance, you would have to convert your class to be immutable , which in-turn returns a separate instance for every method call. DB Transactions would not change what is happening to the property values within PHP.

Example: https://3v4l.org/n2rdC

Comment: The same issue would occur outside of a function call and global usage, since you're just changing the property value of the one instance of DB before executing the query with `DB::get()`. Example: https://3v4l.org/TGLFl

Answer (score 2):

The issue is caused by changing the mutable object properties prior to completing the desired query with `Db::get()`. Resulting in the `Db::$table` property being changed when being called on the same instance of the `Db` class.

This is one of the reasons behind best-practices discouraging the use of [`global`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global), since the intention/context of the current variable state is not easily determined.

What's happening with your code is

```
Db::$table = 'rooms'
Db::$table = 'admin'
Db::$where = 'admin.id =  1'
Db::get() //SELECT * FROM admin WHERE admin.id = 1
Db::$table = null
Db::$where = null
Db::$where = 'rooms.id = 1'
Db::get() //SELECT * FROM WHERE rooms.id = 1
```

---

To avoid the issue and ensure the desired order of operations, you need to call `Db::get()` prior to calling any other `DB` methods that modify the properties of the query issued when calling `DB::get()`.

```
$roomId = example_function('id'); // (int) 1
//SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id = 1

$db->table('rooms')->where('id','=', $roomId)->get(); 
//SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE id = 1
```

Alternatively, to ensure that the intention of two individual queries is preserved, you would need to create a separate instance of `DB` for your second query. However, this would also create a separate `PDO` instance with your current code.

To avoid a second instance of `PDO` you would have to change `$this->connect` to a static property `self::$connect` and refactor any method using `$this->connect` to `self::$connect`. The static property will ensure that only a single instance of PDO will ever exist whenever `new Db()` is called.

```
class Db
{
    protected static $connect;

    //...

    public function __construct() 
    {      
        try {
            if (!isset(self::$connect)) {
                self::$connect = new PDO("{$this->db_database}:host={$this->db_host};dbname={$this->db_name};charset=utf8mb4", "{$this->db_username}", "{$this->db_password}");
                self::$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                self::$connect->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES utf8mb4");
            }
        } catch ( PDOException $e ){
            echo  "<b>Veritabanı bağlantısı sağlanamadı! - Hata Kodu: </b>".$e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }

   //...
}
```

Afterwards replace all usages of `global $db;` in your application with `$db = new Db();`.

This approach will also ensure your entire codebase is protected from the mutable object property overwrite issue and better adheres to best-practices.

```
function example_function($key)
{
    $db = new Db();
    $a_id = 1; // example
    $admins = $db->table('admins')->where('id','=',$a_id)->order('id','desc')->limit(1)->get();
    $admin_data = $admins['data'][0];
    $return = $admin_data[$key];
    return $return;
}

$new = $db->table('rooms')->where('id','=', example_function('id'))->get();
```

---

Another approach *could* be to use `clone` to workaround the mutable object issue. However, **using `clone` will have adverse affects on the `PDO` instance**, since it resides in the `Db` class. Most likely requiring you to separate the PDO connection code from the Query Builder code.

```
function example_function($key)
{
    global $db;
    $db2 = clone $db;
    $a_id = 1; // example
    $admins = $db2->table('admins')->where('id','=',$a_id)->order('id','desc')->limit(1)->get();
    //...
}
```